# Popover Bootstrap - How to make it cleaner

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, web, popover

I am trying to figure out different ways of building a popover without having to declare all of it's attributes in the  tag. Is it possible to group it in a class, or declare it within .popover()?

For example, is it possible to change

```
<a href="#" id="example" class="btn btn-primary" rel="popover"
data-content="This is the body of Popover"
data-original-title="Creativity Tuts">pop
</a>

$(function () {
    $('#example').popover();
});
```

to something cleaner like this

```
<a href="#" id="cleaner" class="btn btn-primary">pop2</a>

$(function () {
    $('cleaner').popover({
        //where I would rather declare rel="popover", 
        //data-content="This is the body of Popover" and so on.
    });
});
```

Here's my [jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/arockwell/zn8gdzhg/4/)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: [Documentation](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/popovers/#usage)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, here you are:

```
$(function () {
    $('#cleaner').popover({
        content : "This is the body of popover",
        title : "Creativity Tuts",
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure:

```
$(function () {
  $('#cleaner').attr({
    'rel': 'popover',
    'data-content': 'This is the body of Popover',
    'data-original-title': 'Creativity Tuts'
  });
  $('#cleaner').popover();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to pay attantion to 
[docs](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_popover.asp)